# Automatically Filling Form Fields in MS Access 2010

Tags: forms, macros, ms-access-2010

Hi I have a table Exhibit_Testing with the following fields:

1) ReferenceNo ( Automatic Number)
2) Region_Name
3) Branch_Code
4)Branch_Name
5) AOM
6) Observation
7) Status
8) Date_Recieved
9) Date_Checked

I want to create a Data Entry Form where if I enter Branch_Code then, Region_Name, Branch_Name, AOM are automatically filled.

Please help me in that. Thanks.

Update : The Branch_Code should be in Combo Box format.

Answer (score 1):

The `Branch_Code` combobox's `RowSource` property should be a query that returns all the fields you want to automatically fill in.

When a particular branch is selected from the combo use the `AfterUpdate` event to fill in the other fields as follows:

```
Private Sub cmbBranch_Code_AfterUpdate()
    txtRegion_Name=cmbBranch_Code.Column(1)
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: how do I make that query

Comment: Use the ellipsis (...) in the `RowSource` property to open the query designer